# Eureka MultivaluedSection don't show add or delete icons

Tags: eureka-forms

I am using the Eureka forms library in Swift but don't appears add or delete icons

This is the code:

```
+++
MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Reorder, .Insert, .Delete],
    header: "Directions",
    footer: "") {
        $0.addButtonProvider = { section in
        return ButtonRow(){
        $0.title = "Add New item"
    }
}
$0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in
    return TextRow { row in
        row.placeholder = "step"
    }
}
$0 <<< TextRow { row in
    row.placeholder = "step"
}
```

}

somebody knows if i am omitted a step or what do i need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just add

```
tableView.isEditing = true
```

in viewDidLoad()